# Set the JAVA_HOME variable before running Axis2 Script

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-12.04, apache-axis

I have installed `axis2-1.6.2` on Ubuntu version 12.04. In the `bin` directory when I run `WSDL2Java.sh` command I get this message:

```
You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running Axis2 Script.
```

But I have set the `JAVA_HOME` variable and when I run :

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please provide the full console output of your wsdl2java command and the result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Replace `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` with the path to your Java install.